# spark override the dataframe variable without using var

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have one API which perform delete operation on dataframe like below

```
def deleteColmns(df:DataFrame,clmList :List[org.apache.spark.sql.Column]):DataFrame{
    var ddf:DataFrame = null 
    for(clm<-clmList){
       ddf.drop(clm)
    }
return ddf
}
```

Since it is not good practice to use the **var** in functional programming , how to avoid this situation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With **Spark >2.0**, you can drop multiple columns using a sequence of column name :

```
val clmList: Seq[Column] = _
val strList: Seq[String] = clmList.map(c => s"$c")
df.drop(strList: _*)
```

Otherwise, you can always use `foldLeft` to fold left on the `DataFrame` and drop your columns :

```
clmList.foldLeft(df)((acc, c) => acc.drop(c))
```

I hope this helps.